# gSheet - Unable to get results using filter in an array

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas, flatten, google-query-language

I'm trying to reference data that has multiple matches using an array formula.
It's not able to find any data.  Yet if I change "DTR!C:C=B:B," to "DTR!C:C=B6, B7, etc," and use the formula outside of the array it works.

I'm trying to list the computer names of users that have more than one computer.

Thanks

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(transpose(
FILTER(
DTR!L:L,DTR!C:C=B:B, 
DTR!B:B="Checked"
DTR!U:U="False",
DTR!V:V="False",
))))
```

**Sample**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dFDl0JFzaBheRkT5LSATDTSnx6bmZezIBtmmSS_tXTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: FILTER is not supported under ARRAYFORMULA. share a copy of your shhet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0  Thanks for looking into this.  You will find the areas marked in Red on the DTR tab.  
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dFDl0JFzaBheRkT5LSATDTSnx6bmZezIBtmmSS_tXTA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in R6:R range and use this in R6:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B6:B, FILTER(
 {DSMT!C:C, DSMT!M:M}, 
 DSMT!B:B="Checked",
 DSMT!U:U="False",
 DSMT!V:V="False"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

next, delete everything in range S6:AA and use this in S6:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B6:B, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(
 {DSMT!C:C&"×", DSMT!M:M, ROW(DSMT!M:M)}, 
 DSMT!B:B="unchecked",
 DSMT!U:U="False",
 DSMT!V:V="False"), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "× ", 1)), 
 SEQUENCE(1, 9)+1, 0)))
```

[image]